# TcColorbox Equal height

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox

I am new to using tcolorbox package.  With the code below I am trying to add space to the third box on the left so that it fills the gap with my graph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,enhanced,title=\textbf{One-Sided Limits},
attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue!75}]
 Consider the function $f(x)$ whose graph is shown below.
 \begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height=rows]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blankest]
        \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1]
            \begin{tcolorbox} What is $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)}$? \end{tcolorbox}
             \begin{tcolorbox} What is $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)}$?\end{tcolorbox}
        
               \begin{tcolorbox} What problem do you run into if you try to find $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)}$ \end{tcolorbox}
        \end{tcbraster}
    \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[width=3in,
grid style={blue!75},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
xmin = -2,   xmax = 3,
ymin = -3,  ymax = 3,
xtick = {-2,-1,...,3},
ytick = {-3,-2,...,3},
xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={above right},
  ylabel style={above right},
axis line style={latex-latex},
]
\addplot[thick,color=blue,domain=-2.2:1] {-x^2+3};
\addplot[thick,color=blue,domain=1:4] {-x+2};

\addplot[color=blue,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(1,1)};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*,fill=white,only marks] coordinates {(1,2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

I must confess that I'm not sure to understand it, but I copied the use of `space to` and `add to natural height` from example in page 317 from `tcolorbox` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    colback=white, enhanced, title=\textbf{One-Sided Limits},
    attach boxed title to top center = {yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
    boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue!75}]
Consider the function $f(x)$ whose graph is shown below.

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows]
    \tcbitem[blankest, space to=\myspace] 
        \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1, raster rows=3]
            \tcbitem What is $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)}$? 
            \tcbitem What is $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)}$?
            \tcbitem[add to natural height=\myspace] What problem do you run into if you try to find $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)}$
        \end{tcbitemize}
    \tcbitem[halign=center] %
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [width=3in, grid style={blue!75},
                 axis x line = center, axis y line = center,
                 xmin = -2,   xmax = 3, ymin = -3,  ymax = 3,
                 xtick = {-2,-1,...,3}, ytick = {-3,-2,...,3},
                 xlabel={$x$},  ylabel={$y$},
                 xlabel style={above right},  ylabel style={above right},
                 axis line style={latex-latex},
            ]
                \addplot[thick,color=blue,domain=-2.2:1] {-x^2+3};
                \addplot[thick,color=blue,domain=1:4] {-x+2};
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=*,only marks] coordinates {(1,1)};
                \addplot[color=blue,mark=*,fill=white,only marks] coordinates {(1,2)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PERFECT!! Thank you for your time